# CAAnimation memory usage in case of chaining

Tags: calayer, avplayer, cgimage, caanimation

I am building photo slideshow by building multiple CALayers, assigning cgimage to the layer's contents, and then adding CAAnimations to each layer. Each layer comes off and goes their start time & go after duration(say 3 seconds). None of the animations overlap in time. Finally all layers are added to AVSynchronizedLayer for playback using AVPlayer.

Problem: How do I defer image loading at the time when respective animation runs ? Currently I do imageLayer.contents = (id) self.image.CGImage while building each layer and it adds to memory usage no matter whether it is visible on screen or not.

I also tried setting CALayer contents by animating the contents property as follows :

```
    CABasicAnimation *contentsAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
    contentsAnimation.beginTime = startTime;
    contentsAnimation.duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.timeRange.duration);
    contentsAnimation.fromValue = (id) self.photoImage.CGImage;
    contentsAnimation.toValue = (id) self.photoImage.CGImage;
    contentsAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    contentsAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    contentsAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

    [imageLayer addAnimation:contentsAnimation forKey:@"contents"];
```

But the problem is since CGImage is referenced, it adds to memory usage. If you have 20 images, size of dirty memory is too much causing crash.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found that the solution was simply putting UIImage loading code inside @autoreleasepool { }. I was putting this autoreleasepool{} at the wrong place earlier. It had nothing to do with CoreAnimation as such.